# Python hangs when I call imshow

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pycharm, imshow

```
from pylab import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
import random
import time
from scipy.misc import imread
from scipy.misc import imresize
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import os


# General setup
matplotlib
#gray()


# 2D Array
a = array([[4,5,6], [1,2,3]])

# shape of matrix in format n x m
a.shape

# Read in an image
i = imread('test.jpg')





if __name__ == "__main__":

    imshow(i)   # HANGS ON OSX
    plt.show()
```

This code runs completely fine on my windows machine, but on MacOSX it hangs whenever I call imshow (even on a trivial array), the image window pops up but it hangs. I am using pycharm.

Anybody know why this is? Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "hangs"? Does it crash? Can you use it? What?

Comment: The image window pops up but it is non responsive, I see the spinning wheel, the image doesnt show up, just a unresponsive window that i have to terminate from the activity monitor

Comment: how did you install all of this stuff? probably doesn't matter. if you didn't use anaconda/conda, you should.

Comment: Did you ever fix this problem?

Comment: I am using anaconda. Also, i didn't fix it but I found a way to make it sort of work. When the window hangs i realized it still takes inputs, so I would call pause(1) everytime I interact with the window to advance to window one frame at a time. Not a solid sollution but at least i can get some work done like this at least